# How to call the javascript function dynamically

Tags: javascript

I need to call the javascript function dynamically after some delay, The function display_1, 2, ... n will be dynamically constructed. My script looks like this, but the function never gets triggered if I use the following code, but if I hardcode the function it just seems to be fine.

```
function display_1() {
alert(1);
}

function display_2() {
alert(2);
}

function display() {
var prefix = 'display_';
for(var i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
setTimeout(prefix.concat(i), 1000);
}

window.onload = display();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to add the parenthesis so that the function is called:

```
setTimeout(prefix.concat(i)+"()", 1000);
```

or simply:

```
setTimeout(prefix + i + "()", 1000);
```

Besides of that please note that both functions are called pratically at the same time, because the timers started with ´setTimeout()` *start* at the same time.

Depending on what you're trying to do you might have a look at `setInterval()` or start the second timeout at the end of the `display_1()` function.

Comment: +1 for also mentioning the asynchronous nature of `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of going via a string, you may as well group the functions into an array:

```
function display_1() {...}

function display_2() { ... }

var functions = [ display_1, display_2 ];

function display() {
   for( var i = 0; i != functions.length; ++i ) { 
     setTimeout( functions[i], 1000 );
   }
 }
```

If you want to go further, you may even leave out the explicit function names:

```
var functions = [
    function() { /*the function_1 implementation*/ 
    },
    function() { /*the function_2 implementation*/
    }
];
```

Comment: just curious: is there a special reason for using `i != functions.length` instead of `i < functions.length`?

Comment: also, I think there is a typo: the parenthesis shouldn't be there in the first argument to `setTimeout()` since you want to pass the function *reference* and not call it immediately.

Comment: @Udo: the `i != imax` is a way to make sure that after you leave the loop, `i == imax`.  If you use `i < imax`, after the loop, `i >= imax`.  If you want to proof that only `imax` elements have been iterated over, you need to involve recursion in your proof.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
function display_1() {
alert(1);
}

function display_2() {
alert(2);
}

function display() {
var prefix = 'display_';
for(var i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
setTimeout(prefix.concat(i)+'()', 1000);
}
}

window.onload = display;
```

1. the string passed to setTimeout should call the function
2. onload should be set to a function, not its return value

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval('load_testimonial()',5000);//first parameter is your function or what ever the code u want to execute, and second is time in millisecond..
```

this will help you to execute your function for every given time.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a 1000ms delay between executing the functions, you could do something like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var n = 0;
    var functions = [
        function() {
            alert(1);
            setTimeout(functions[n++], 1000);
        },
        function() {
            alert(2);
            setTimeout(functions[n++], 1000);
        },
        function() {
            alert(3);
        }
    ];
    setTimeout(functions[n++], 1000);
};
```

(rewrite it in a less-repetitive nature if needed)