# How to execute a JavaScript function when I send its name as string dynamically without parameters

Tags: javascript

I want execute JavaScript function which the name is coming as a string dynamically.
I don't need to pass any parameters while executing the function.

Please can any one guide me how to achieve this?

Comment: eval is evil, try to avoid it at all costs

Comment: Check this threads

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676721/calling-dynamic-function-with-dynamic-parameters-in-javascript

and

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618007/how-to-call-the-javascript-function-dynamically

Answer (score 1):

one simple way

```
eval("SomeFunction()");
```

or

```
var funcName = "SomeFunction";
var func == window[funcName];
func();
```

Answer (score 0):

dangerous but you could use `eval(method_name+"()")`

Answer (score 0):

are you talking about ´eval()´??

```
var foo = "alert('bar')";
eval(foo);
```

Hope this helps;

Answer (score 0):

```
function a() { 
   console.log('yeah!'); 
}

var funcName = 'a'; // get function name

this[funcName]();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the function is global, you should do `window[funcName]()` in browser.

Comment: You chould check if it exists with `if ("function" === typeof window[funcName])`

Comment: window[funcName]() it is working in Firefox but not working in IE8 Iam getting error in IE8 is expected identifier

Answer (score 0):

Using `eval` is the worst way imaginable. Avoid that at all costs.

You can use `window[functionname]()` like this:

```
function myfunction() {
    alert('test');
}

var functionname = 'myfunction';
window[functionname]();
```

This way you can optionally add arguments as well

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a safer way is to do something like this (pseudo code only here):

```
function executer(functionName)
{
  if (functionName === "blammo")
  {
    blammo();
  }
  else if (functionName === "kapow")
  {
    kapow();
  }
  else // unrecognized function name
  {
    // do something.
  }
```

You might use a switch statement for this (it seems like a better construct):

```
switch (functionName)
{
  case "blammo":
    blammo();
    break;

  case "kapow":
    kapow();
    break;

  default:
    // unrecognized function name.
}
```

You can optimize this by creating an array of function names, searching the array for the desired function name, then executing the value in the array.